# pyplot contourf: How can I make the colors in the chart continuous?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use `contourf`, `matplotlib` chooses to group the values into similar regions and color those regions. How can I make this plot show the full spectrum of different values? In the code below, I want the colors to be continuous, so that sun over the hill is a gradient of increasing colors, instead of these sudden changes in color.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, vmin = 0., vmax = 3., cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of the word "contour," `contourf` plots and fills discrete contours. You may want to consider `plt.imshow` instead.

```
plt.imshow(Z, vmin = 0., vmax = 3., cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, origin='lower', 
           extent=[X.min(), X.max(), Y.min(), Y.max()])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My problem with this is that I can't specify the x and y values like I can in contourf.

Comment: I changed the answer, it takes care of the labels now.

Comment: For future reference, if you want the peaks to be redder then you need to change your vmax=3 to  Z.max()

Answer (score 6):

A quick workaround would be to make the levels that the contour plot uses very small. Don't use vmin and vmax.

```
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
clev = np.arange(Z.min(),Z.max(),.001) #Adjust the .001 to get finer gradient
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, clev, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm)
plt.show()
```

**EDIT**
If you just want the top part more continous play around with the lower and upper bounds of the contour levels.

```
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)
clev = np.arange(0,Z.max(),.001) #Adjust the .001 to get finer gradient
CS = plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, clev, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,extend='both')
plt.show()
```

[image]